# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '=' error

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can help me with this one. I am getting this error:

Set-iOSversion -TenantId 123456-abcd-12345-abcd-12345678 -Client …
*A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '='*

```
     pool:
  name: 'default'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  paths:
    include:
    - 'mydomain.com'

pr: none

variables:
  working_dir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\AzDO\dev

jobs:
  - job: iOSminimumversion
    steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: UniversalPackages@0
        inputs:
          command: 'download'
          downloadDirectory: '$(working_dir)'
          feedsToUse: 'internal'
          vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxx'
          vstsFeedPackage: 'intune-iosversion'
          vstsPackageVersion: '*'
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Import-Module $(working_dir)\scripts\DeviceCompliance\Update-iOSversion.ps1
            Write-Host "Updating Device Compliance policies in nbimdev.onmicrosoft.com"
            Set-iOSversion -TenantId $(TenantId) -ClientId $(CLIENTID) -ClientSecret $env:MAPPED_SECRET -JSONPath "$(working_dir)\configs\DeviceCompliance\"
        env:
          MAPPED_SECRET: $(SECRET)
```

(I substituted the actual numbers but there are no equal signs anywhere)

-TenantId 123456-abcd-12345-abcd-12345678 -ClientId 123456-abcd-1234-1234-12345678 -ClientSecret $env:MAPPED_SECRET -JSONPath /opt/azdoagent/_work/1/s/AzDO/dev/configs/\DeviceCompliance\

But from what I can see there is nothing in my parameters that has an = sign at all? Is there anything else I could be missing here? Appreciate the assistance!

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gek8B.png)

Comment: "script:" is not a built in drive.  What is the point of it?  The "|" is confusing me.

Comment: I am guessing that "$(working_dir)" should be $($working_dir).

Comment: $(TenantId) should be $($TenantId) and $(CLIENTID)  should be $($CLIENTID) .

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I tried what you suggested but it gave this error: Line |
   4 |  Set-iOSversion -TenantId $($TenantId) -ClientId $($CLIENTID) -ClientS …
     |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TenantId' because it is an
     | empty string.

Comment: In my original code, I do see that the variables are being sent in correctly too

Comment: it looks like you are calling the PoSh code from inside another program. is that the case?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes. Sorry I've attached my whole code now

Comment: Maybe `$env:MAPPED_SECRET` has got a Base64 encoded string? Those often contain `=` as padding.

Comment: @vonPryz thanks. I tried to write-host $env:MAPPED_SECRET and can see it is just outputting ***. Assuming it is correctly passing the secret through but any ideas how I can check? This one is really stumping me :D

Comment: I got it to work! It wasn't actually the line stated in the error but the script it was calling in the function. There was a variable which was mis-assigned.. Thanks all

Comment: @Draylan - glad to know that you found the glitch & fixed it. [*grin*]

Comment: Was this the "-JSONPath /opt/azdoagent/_work/1/s/AzDO/dev/configs/\DeviceCompliance\" the mis-assigned variable.  "/\" is invalid in JSON query.